# Transform XmlNode into XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml

I wonder what is the best way to turn a `XmlNode` object into an `XmlReader`... I could even name a few ways to do this ... But they use a `MemoryStream` to make the transformation.

```
XmlNode content = // My data
using (System.IO.MemoryStream mm = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    using (System.Xml.XmlWriter wtr = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(mm))
    {
        content.WriteTo(wtr);
        wtr.Flush();
        mm.Position = 0;
        using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(mm))
        {
            // Here I have the object
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use the [`XmlNodeReader` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader.xmlnodereader):

```
using (XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(content))
{
    // ...
}
```

(The documentation says you should use `XmlReader.Create` - but there are no overloads taking an `XmlNode`, so that doesn't seem terribly useful to me...)